# Angular 6: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6, angular-observable

I am upgrading my app to **Angular 6**. I am upgrading from **Angular 4**, but the code below is causing errors in Angular 6, where it worked fine in Angular 4.

---

The errors I am getting:

> Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'
>
> Error: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable'

How should I resolve these errors?

```
  private authInterceptor(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch((error, source) => {
      if (error.status == 401) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        return Observable.of();
      } else {
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since you tagged your question rxjs6, I'm assuming the upgrade to Angular 6 includes an upgrade to rxjs6. In that case, it's not working because methods on the observable object are now standalone operators that you can apply using pipe(). Also, imports have changed. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) for more details.

With rxjs6 it should look something like this:

```
import { Observable, EMPTY, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

private authInterceptor(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
   return observable.pipe(
       catchError( err => {
            if (err.status == 401) {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                return EMPTY;
            } else {
                return throwError(err);
            }
       })
   );
 }
```

Comment: I'm using this pipe like this and cannot make the catchError to work, what's wrong?public login(params:object) {
        this.loading.show(null);
        return this.http.post(this.config.server + this.config.login, params).pipe(map(response=>{
            this.loading.hide();
            let authResponse = new AuthenticationResponseModel(response);
            return authResponse;
        }));
    }

Comment: @LuisParada it looks like you forgot to actually include catchError? At least it's not in the code you pasted

Comment: the catchError is in the code, I cannot paste all the code, is in NS typescript and is very long to add it to a comment.

Comment: I need to add the catchError in the "pipe(map()" segment of the code, and cannot have it working, I tried adding "," after the second parenthesys of map function and it accepts the structure but I receive a problem that the returned object is not of the type I'm creating it.}

Comment: public login(params:object) {
        this.loading.show(null);
        return this.http.post(this.config.server + this.config.login, params).pipe(map(response=>{
                this.loading.hide();
                let authResponse = new AuthenticationResponseModel(response);
                return authResponse;
            }), catchError((err) => {
                this.handleErrors(err);
                return err;
            })
        );
    }

Comment: @LuisParada if you explain your problem in a separate question and post the link here, I will try to help you.

Comment: I resoved the issue, new rxjs uses operators as stand alone, and now are not a part of observables, so, we have the observable stack function which starts with the function to execute and then errors and more, so basically we have to change the dot notation with new Observable((func1)=>{}, catchError()); so that was enough.

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Or import Observable this way:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: than try import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Answer (score 3):

Import the Library with following method and rearrange the code

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
return Observable.pipe(catchError =>...);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have migrated to RXJS6 since you have also migrated to angular6.

In RXJS6 use catch Error instead of catch as seen [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

```
  import {catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
  import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to import the catch operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Comment: I have added import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'; but its not working.

Comment: which rxjs version are u uing

Answer (score 1):

you will need to import all operators you are using.

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all install the rxjs packages using below command

```
npm i rxjs-compat
```

then import the libraries using

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Or import Observable this way:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But in this case, you import all operators.

got from below link
https://code-examples.net/en/q/235b329

Comment: rxjs-compat is not permamanent. it is just hekpful to migrate from rxjs 5 ot 6. this will work for very short time until compat is gone

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I'am using Angular 6.1.0.

```js
import { Observable, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.ofertas = this.subjectPesquisa // Retorno Oferta[]
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000)) // Executa a ação do switchMap após 1 segundo
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) // Apenas executa a ação switchMap se o termo enviado for outro
  .pipe(switchMap((termo: string) => {

    if (termo.trim() === '') {
      // Retornar um observable de array de ofertas vazio.
      return of<Oferta[]>([]);
    }

    console.log('Requisição HTTP para api: ', termo);
    return this.ofertasService.pesquisaOfertas(termo);
  }))
  .pipe(catchError((err: any) => {
    console.log('Erro: ', catchError);
    return of<Oferta[]>([]);
  }));
```